# JBOSS + HSQLDB setting the .script

Tags: hsqldb

Please Advice me how to add/modify .script to add checkpoint defrag in HSQLDB JBOSS

some configuration in hsqldb-ds.xml

```
<connection-url>jdbc:hsqldb:${jboss.server.data.dir}${/}hypersonic${/}localDB</connection-url>  

  <!-- The login and password -->
  <user-name>sa</user-name>
  <password></password>

<mbean code="org.jboss.jdbc.HypersonicDatabase" 
 name="jboss:service=Hypersonic,database=localDB">
 <attribute name="Database">localDB</attribute>
 <attribute name="InProcessMode">true</attribute>
```

Please advice which part it will be create the automatic script : localDB.script

I want to add the checkpoint defrag in that script using DatabaseManager
I was facing that database and log file increasing with the huge size.
When error, i will delete all the entire files and restart the JBOSS again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just managed to solve it !

Edit your file deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml

Inside, you will find a commented tag new-connection-sql.

Uncomment it, and insert the SQL command that is equivalent to the property hsqldb.defrag_limit:

> ```
> <new-connection-sql>SET CHECKPOINT DEFRAG 0</new-connection-sql>
> ```

(I'm working with hsqldb 1.8.0, the defrag occurs for me only when I set it to 0)

Voilà !